# Local maxima search of a multivariable function

Tags: algorithm, search, optimization, local, maxima

I am looking for an algorithm to search for local maxima of a multivariable function (unknown derivative, sadly).

History:

For the past three years, I have been dealing with only 6-D surfaces and the general algorithm was to:

1. Set up a uniform grid and perform a calculation at each point. (~500M – 1G points to ascertain at least some form of accuracy; 1 point takes <1 ms to calculate varying according to input - parallelized)
2. Search for local maxima in an array of the points.
3. Optimize the local maxima using BFGS algorithm => local maxima.

Present:

Well, now, we need to deal with 12-D to 18-D functions and this makes the previous algorithm impossible to maintain. We have decided to alleviate some of the hurdles by using Smolyak grid to set up Chebyshev polynomials and search within this approximate hyperspace. But this provides relatively only a little speedup to the problem and now we are left with searching for maxima on these Chebyshev polynomials. Sadly, I am only a little mathematician and more of a computational chemists.

My questions are, which I tried to research to no avail:

1. Are there any algorithms to search for local maxima on multivariable function? (Other than multiple reset of some stochastic heuristic like simulated annealing/particle swarm method?)
2. Is it possible to exploit the form of Chebyshev polynomials to help us find the local maxima on this approximate hyperspace effectively? Is there any effective algorithm to search for at least extrema of Chebyshev polynomials using its derivative and subsequently couple it with second derivative calculation?

My ideas involved the computer vision, as I believe local maxima search should be daily bread in this dept. of science? Within chemistry, global maxima are the stars of the show usually making my field of view very limited sadly. I am a bit overwhelmed by the dimensionality of the problem.

I feel a bit stuck in a loop. Any kick in the right directions is much appreciated!

Zaf

Additional info: The algorithm has been and will be used for an in-house baked program written in Fortran.

Comment: Without gradients, look into DFO (Derivative-Free Optimization). This is a well-studied area of research,

Comment: Anything known about the function?
- Maybe some clusters of the 12D seems to be more independent?
- What are the cost of 1, or 1000 evaluations of the function?
- Say A, and B, are pretty low, any sensible way to combine both proposals? If so, try Genetic

Comment: Very interesting question, however, it's not really suitable for SO. Try math.stackexchange.com instead.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen Thank you. As you have proposed to use DFO's. Is there any rule of thumb for when to decide between numerical gradients and DFO?

Comment: @user3184950 Thank you, well, I feel like it will end up with something like that or particle swarm.

Comment: @RobertDodier Thank you, wilco.

Comment: There are some big drawbacks when using finite differences. (1) you need to do a large number of function evaluations (2) you lose about half of the precision.

Comment: A good reference on DFO algorithms is https://rd.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10898-012-9951-y